# Universal register machine that recognizes the image of a partial function

Tags: computability, computation-models

Suppose $f$ is a $\mathbb N$-valued partial function over a subset of $\mathbb N$. If $f$ is computable by a universal register machine program, is the constant partial function
$$
g:\text{image}(f)\to\mathbb N
$$
defined by $g(x)=1$ for $x\in\text{image}(f)$ and undefined elsewhere also computable by a universal register machine program?

If $f$ is total then I can understand how to define a program for $g$: given input $x$, check if $f(0)=x,f(1)=x,\dots$ and if eventually I find $y$ such that $f(y)=x$ then return $1$. But this process does not seem to work when $f$ is partial: $f(0)$ may cause the program to loop, for instance. Any hints would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you familiar with dovetailing?

Comment: I considered this form of dovetailing: compute $f(0)$ by one step; compute $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ by one step; compute $f(0),f(1),f(2)$ by one step, etc. Is this the correct approach? I'm having difficulty coming up with how such a program would be coded using the usual register machine instructions.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, register machines are equivalent to Turing machines. In particular, they can do whatever a Turing machine can do, dovetailing included.

Comment: Yes, it's clear to me now-thank you very much